# How to pass data to Oboe.js

Tags: javascript, oboe.js

> Originally asked by Sashkan on the [Oboe.js Github issues](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js/issues/76):

Is 'data' handled by oboe.js ?

I've been using oboe to stream response from an API. Everything works great with all of the calls that does not require parameters, but how can I work with parameters-dependant calls ?

```
// basic ajax request for my call is
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});

// 'data' is my parameters list, as a json string. How can I pass it to oboe ?
oboe(url)
    .done(function(things) {
        alert('success');
        console.log(things);
    })
    .fail(function(test) {
        alert( "ERROR:  " + test );
        console.log(test);
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Answer provided by JuanCaicedo

You can pass a configuration object into the oboe function, the pass your data as the request body (you might have to format this according to how the API expects it). You can find more details in http://oboejs.com/api.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
oboe({
    'url': url,
    'method': 'POST',   //optional
    'body': data    //no need to encode, the library will JSON stringify it automatically
}).on('done',function(things){
    //do something with things
});
```

Comment: One of the key advantages of using oboe.js for streaming instead of websockets is that it allows browsers and servers to automatically cache the response. Using POST removes this advantage.

Comment: @JeremiahRose and what about if you hit the querystring limit with your parameters?

Comment: In that situation, your solution would work better. It would be a tradeoff between cacheability vs being able to send an infinite number of request queries

Comment: Using POST is required (not "optional") if the server is responding according to the data in the body. Using GET in this scenario is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a RESTful way to do this using cacheable GET requests, it is simply a matter of adding the query parameters to the URI like so:

```
var query = $.param(data);

oboe(url+"?"+query)
.done(function(things) {
    alert('success');
    console.log(things);
})
.fail(function(test) {
    alert( "ERROR:  " + test );
    console.log(test);
});
```

Note that I am using JQuery